# Where can I download Azure SDK for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: azure

Has anyone recently tried to download Azure SDK for Visual Studio 2010? Going to the Azure site doesn't give the option any more; it only allows downloading SDK for VS2012 and VS2013.

Is VS2010 no longer supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Azure SDK and Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio (March 2011)
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15658

it should not give you any problems.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) and search for "`azure 2010`".

The Azure 2.1 SDK is available for Visual Studio 2010 (with SP1).

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to download the latest SDK (version 2.2), it is not supported for VS 2010. See this blog post from Scott Guthrie: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/10/22/windows-azure-announcing-release-of-windows-azure-sdk-2-2-with-lots-of-goodies.aspx. You should be able to download/install earlier versions of SDK using Web Platform Installer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not working with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. The web platform installer is responding with a list of errors.

Comment: For all those that stumble across the same problem: If you try to install via the web platform installer you need to install the bugfix manually for the update where it throws an error (KB2591016). With this update I had to insert the Visual Studio Ultimate CD (or an image) and then install the update. After that the update via the web platform installer worked (some Azure tools could not be installed though)